# What is the Dynamic Provider equivalent for UIImages?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uicolor, ios-darkmode

We can use dynamic providers to extent UIColor classes and have colors that change immediately to dark and light modes, like this

```
extension UIColor {
  static var myControlBackground: UIColor {
      return UIColor { (traits) -> UIColor in
        // Return one of two colors depending on light or dark mode
        return traits.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ?
          UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.4, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1) :
          UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.4, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
      }
  }
}
```

But what about UIImages?

I know that you can use this method

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
  if traitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo:
                                                 previousTraitCollection) {
    // Color change detected.
    // Adjust the interface accordingly.
  }
}
```

the problem is that this method doe not detect changes if the app is in background when the change occurs. And the color dynamic method does.

Any ideas

Comment: `traitCollectionDidChange` does not detect changes if the app is in background when the appearance changes.

Comment: I want to understand if I can do that programmatically, or in other words, without using Image Sets inside Assets Catalog.  Create a way images change to their dark/light equivalents automatically when appearance changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the UIImageAsset class:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageasset

Basically, you make an image asset along with versions of the UIImage for different trait collections, and call `register` on the image asset with the image along with its corresponding trait collection.

Comment: Excellent. I was looking for the same, BUT I would like to register images related to my own themes (not only dark or light, but also a halloween theme, for example). I do this with colors and dynamicProvider, and works great, but I'm not sure how to do that with images... Do you know @matt if that is possible?

Comment: @ernewston How do you do it with colors and dynamic provider? You can't make up a custom trait (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: `var background = UIColor { _ in switch theme { case .light: return color1 case .dark: return color2 case .halloween: return color3 } }`. I don't why apple limited appearances to only two, would be great to have N custom traits to handle themes...

Comment: @ernewston Ah, I see. Well, that's not a color "dynamic provider". You didn't make a live dynamic color, like Apple's. Your interface colors don't magically change when you change the theme, the way Apple's do; you just made a method that returns a color at the time that you call it. Nothing special there. So you could do exactly the same with for your image.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear enough. The example above is the same as writing `var background = UIColor(dynamicProvider: { _ in switch theme { case .light: return color1 case .dark: return color2 case .halloween: return color3 } })`. It does magically change colors when changing darkmode/lightmode.

Comment: @ernewston But not when changing the theme to `.halloween`.

Comment: Yep, that's true. :(